# Can't seem to get CodernityDB index to work

Tags: python, codernity

I am trying out CodernityDB in one of my projects. I got the minitwit example running, but trying out some of the example code in my project does not seem to work. What do I seem to miss?

```
from CodernityDB.database_thread_safe import ThreadSafeDatabase
from CodernityDB.hash_index import HashIndex

import uuid

class PumpIndex(HashIndex):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['key_format'] = '32s'
        super(PumpIndex, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def make_key_value(self, data):
        if data['t'] == 'pump':
            id = data['id']
            # if not isinstance(login, basestring):
            #     login = str(login)
            return id, {'name': data['name']}

    def make_key(self, key):
        return key

    def run_all(self, db):
        it = db.get_many(self.name, with_doc=True)
        for curr in it:
            curr['id'] = curr['doc']['id']
            curr['name'] = curr['doc']['name']
            curr['hardware_type'] = curr['doc']['hardware_type']
            curr['onboard_pump_id'] = curr['doc']['onboard_pump_id']
            curr['pressure_sensor_id'] = curr['doc']['pressure_sensor_id']
            curr['pressure_min'] = curr['doc']['pressure_min']
            curr['pressure_max'] = curr['doc']['pressure_max']
            curr['ignore_errors'] = curr['doc']['ignore_errors']
            curr['simultaneous_zones'] = curr['doc']['simultaneous_zones']
            del curr['doc']
            yield curr

db = ThreadSafeDatabase('~/Desktop/test')

if db.exists():
    db.open()
    db.reindex()
else:

    db.create()
    db.add_index(PumpIndex(db.path, 'pump'))

for x in range(0,10):
    id = uuid.uuid4().hex
    name = 'Test %d' % x
    db.insert(dict(
                t='pump',
                id=id,
                name=name,
                hardware_type="onboard",
                onboard_pump_id=None,
                pressure_sensor_id=None,
                pressure_min=None,
                pressure_max=None,
                ignore_errors=None,
                simultaneous_zones=None
            ))

print int(db.count(db.get_many, 'pump'))
print int(len(list(db.run('pump', 'all'))))
```

The console output I get:

```
{'status': 'o', 'start': 100, 'self': <CodernityDB.storage.IU_Storage object at 0x10bb1ed50>, 'size': 204}
{'status': 'o', 'start': 304, 'self': <CodernityDB.storage.IU_Storage object at 0x10bb1ed50>, 'size': 204}
{'status': 'o', 'start': 508, 'self': <CodernityDB.storage.IU_Storage object at 0x10bb1ed50>, 'size': 204}
{'status': 'o', 'start': 712, 'self': <CodernityDB.storage.IU_Storage object at 0x10bb1ed50>, 'size': 204}
{'status': 'o', 'start': 916, 'self': <CodernityDB.storage.IU_Storage object at 0x10bb1ed50>, 'size': 204}
{'status': 'o', 'start': 1120, 'self': <CodernityDB.storage.IU_Storage object at 0x10bb1ed50>, 'size': 204}
{'status': 'o', 'start': 1324, 'self': <CodernityDB.storage.IU_Storage object at 0x10bb1ed50>, 'size': 204}
{'status': 'o', 'start': 1528, 'self': <CodernityDB.storage.IU_Storage object at 0x10bb1ed50>, 'size': 204}
{'status': 'o', 'start': 1732, 'self': <CodernityDB.storage.IU_Storage object at 0x10bb1ed50>, 'size': 204}
{'status': 'o', 'start': 1936, 'self': <CodernityDB.storage.IU_Storage object at 0x10bb1ed50>, 'size': 204}
0
0
```

Another question, is it possible to not get the status output of Codernity? Its useful for development, but not so much for production.

Comment: Did you discover how to remove the console print-out?

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of hunting I've discovered the spurious print.

Within `CodernityDB\storage.py::135` The `get()` method prints the *locals*:

```
    def get(self, start, size, status='c'):
       if status == 'd':
           return None
       else:
           print locals()
           self._f.seek(start)
           return self.data_from(self._f.read(size))
```

Without editing the site-package I've monkey-patched the method with my own.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the method `get_many` on returns multiple data for given key. Thus it will not return all data. Use the `all` method instead.

```
db.count(db.all, 'pump')
```